# Range Of An Interaction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, interactions, effective-field-theory, carrier-particles

Why is the [Compton wavelength](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_wavelength) $\lambda_c=\frac{\hbar}{mc}$ used as a *sensible measure* for the range of an interaction, where $m$ is the mass of the corresponding mediator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For massive force carriers, one finds (in natural units) an exponential dependence $\mathrm{e}^{-mr}$ that prevents long-range forces with massive mediators. Restoring SI units, one sees that the compton wavelength is the length at which the damping is exactly $\mathrm{e}^{-1}$.

Comment: @Roopam: For a derivation of ACuriousMind's answer, see D. Tong's quantum field theory notes.